# What, if anything, is wrong with a child class containing a parent class object in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

In C++ specifically, but also generally as an OO design principle, is there anything wrong with doing the following? Is it done in practice? If it shows a clear design flaw, what is a good alternative? Are there any advantages?

```
class Property {};
class CompositeProperty : public Property 
{
    ...
    private:
        std::vector<Property> m_properties;
};
```

So specifically, can a derived class contain base class objects?

As I bit of background I have seen this used to model/mirror an XML structure but felt the design somewhat went in the face of is-a-is-inheritance and has-a-is-composition relationships for which one usually strives.

Comment: Nothing wrong (except missing semicolons), but generally a questionable approach. One motto is to have all non-leaf classes abstract, so you shouldn't/wouldn't have a vector of base objects. Furthermore, "parent"/"child" is a very poor metaphor for OOP. A much better one is "base" and "derived"...

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks for the pointers, I will use base and derived in the future and I have added the semicolons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no flaw in design - in fact, this design is only one step away from the well-known and very useful [*composite pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). However, there is a significant flaw in the implementation.

Your `CompositeProperty` aggregates instances of `Property`, rather than aggregating pointers. This kills the ability to use elements of the `CompositeProperty` polymorphically. You need to replace a vector of instances with a vector of pointers (preferably, smart pointers) in order to address this issue.

A classic place for the composite pattern is representation of expression trees: you start off with an abstract base, and then add representations for constants, variables, function calls, unary expressions, binary expressions, conditionals, and so on. Expressions such as constants and variables do not reference other expressions, while expressions such as unary expressions, binary expressions, and function calls do. This makes the object graph recursive, letting you represent expressions of arbitrary complexity.

Answer (score 2):

> So specifically, can a child class contain parent class objects?

In short `YES`

Comment: Is there a good long answer, I have already seen it in a big project but was looking for a more in depth answer?

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the [Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

> Composite can be used when clients should ignore the difference between compositions of objects and individual objects. If programmers find that they are using multiple objects in the same way, and often have nearly identical code to handle each of them, then composite is a good choice; it is less complex in this situation to treat primitives and composites as homogeneous.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with it.

Take this example (it's C#, but should be straightforward enough) where you define two sub-classes each containing an instance of the inherited one:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name;
}

public class MalePerson : Person
{
    public Person BestFriend;
}

public class FemalePerson : Person
{
    public Person BestFriend;
}
```

In my experience, including an instance of the superclass in the subclasses is most commonly used to either model a hierarchy between heterogeneous objects or refer to an object with as few assumptions as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with it at all but you may want to consider using pointers to the base/parent class. This allows for polymorphic behaviour of your objects. If you add instances of derived classes to your vector as it stands, you will suffer from object slicing.